# Showing a linear functional attains a maximum

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Can you help me with the following problem?

Show that the linear function $df_p : \mathbb{R}_p^n \to \mathbb{R}$ restricted on the sphere with center p and radius 1 has maximum value when $v=\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$

Comment: what is $\mathbb R^n_p$?

Comment: Tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(U,\phi) = (U,x^1,...,x^n)$ be a parametrization about $p$. By restricting $\mathbb{R}^n_p$ to $S^n$, we are requiring that all vectors be unit length. Given a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}_p^n$, there exists a smooth curve $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. Hence we have,

\begin{align*} df_p \cdot v &= (f \circ \gamma)'(0) \\ &=  \nabla f(p) \cdot \gamma'(0) \\ & = |\nabla f(p)| \cdot |v| \ \cos \nu \end{align*}

Thus, the maximum is achieved when $\nu = 0 \Rightarrow v = \lambda \nabla f(p)$ where $\lambda >0$. Since $v$ is unit length due to our restriction, it follows that,

$$ v= \frac{\nabla f(p)}{|\nabla f(p)|}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. You answered my question